# How to handle Waiting times between test executions

Tags: selenium, jenkins, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

In Jenkins, I have job created for executing automated tests from xray (Test management tool from jira) . In my test execution there are three test cases, each test case needs to wait for one hour or more to run next test cases . how can i handle the wait times automatically without triggering from jira manually.

Comment: Why do you want an hour gap between test runs? Is this a technical issue, where tests will fail when executed inside this 1-hour gap, or do you want to give Jenkins an opportunity to run other tests?

Comment: Its not technical issue, Result of first test case is dependent on the second one. In my case , the first test case generates unique ticket number which i have to wait for one to two hours of time. At the moment i manually wait for one or two hours and trigger second test case . i want to automate it

Comment: That is essential information for your question. Please post that in the question itself instead of a comment, so other readers can find it easily.

Comment: Have you looked into build pipelines in Jenkins? I haven't played around with them much, but the idea is your "build" is a multi step process, where each subsequent step requires the success of a previous step.

Comment: I think the challenge is to set up two nodes in the pipeline, and getting Jenkins to wait for an hour in between execution of those two nodes.